# How do you build strings concatenated with int variables in C?

Tags: c, string, concatenation, string-concatenation

String manipulation in C is *not* something I'm used to, coming from higher level languages. In this situation, I want to be able to make a string of the form `fooN` where N is a variable representing a number. In Java, it would look something like

```
for (int N = 0; N < 5; n++) {
    System.out.println("foo"+N);
}
```

which will output

```
foo0
foo1
foo2
foo3
foo4
```

However, I don't know a straighforward way to do that in C. I could probably hack something out where I make a char[] and figure out how to fill it up, but what I have in mind doesn't seem elegant. Is there a simple way that the C language allows concatenating strings and int variables?

Thanks

Comment: Look up `sprintf`.  It's similar to `String.format`.

Comment: `printf("foo%d", N);`

Comment: First you need to decide whether you're making a string, or just displaying a string. Your Java example conflates the two (you made a string before displaying it, because the syntax makes that easy). But in C, making a string, and displaying a string are very different tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a simple way that the C language allows concatenating strings and int variables?

Yes, use `s*printf()`.  The trick is memory management.

1. Use a fixed sized buffer.

   ```
   // Coarse calculation of maximum memory needed to string-ify an int
   #define INT_STRING_MAX (sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT/3 + 3)
   #define FOO_SZ (3 + INT_STRING_MAX)

   char buf[FOO_SZ];
   sprintf(buf, "foo%d", n);
   println(buf);
   ```
2. Allocate memory.  Could use `snprintf(NULL, 0, ...` to calculate memory needs.

   ```
   int sz = snprintf(NULL, 0, "foo%d", n);
   char *buf = malloc(sz + 1);
   if (buf) {
     sprintf(buf, "foo%d", n);
     println(buf);
     free(buf);
   }
   ```
3. Estimate and check memory needs with `snprintf()`.

   ```
   // Assume 64-bit or narrower int and so needs at most 21 bytes
   #define FOO_SZ (3 + 21)

   char buf[FOO_SZ];
   int cnt = snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "foo%d", n);
   if (cnt >= 0 && (unsigned) cnt < sizeof buf) {
     println(buf);
   } else {
     // wrong estimate
   }
   ```

The best choice depends on how simple, efficient & portable you want.

Comment: note that for robust code you should also check `sz > 0` , since snprintf can fail and return a negative error code. I have heard of this happening in situations such as a UTF-8 locale where the input contained invalid UTF-8. (And also this method won't work if the input can exceed `INT_MAX`)

Comment: @M.M All true.  And more trouble should needed string exceed `SIZE_MAX`.   With different _locales_, all bets are off too.  The singular issue with detecting particular failures is how to handle them once found.  IMO, knowing that tends to drive the design.  For here and now - some of the basics.